How to display Vue components in Tabulator cell
So, I've been doing a bit of searching on google and here on SO to figure out how to have a vue component displayed in a tabulator table cell.  Most of what I've seen is very outdated (3-4+ years old) and doesn't really seem to help.
My current stack:

vue 3.3.4 (I'm using composition api)
tabluator-tables 6.3.0
quasar 2.14.0

I'm loving tabluator so far, however it is critical that I be able to render a component within the table.  I've seen a few things that talk about dynamically creating and rendering a vue component and then injecting the html, but that seems very dirty and complex.
Is there any updated info or strategies on how one might put a vue component into a table cell?

You need to create a VNode and render it inside the cell component after the cell has been rendered. I used a column formatter with the following code:
formatter: (cell, _, onRender) => {
    onRender(() => {
        render(createVNode(MyComponent, props), cell.getElement());
    });
    return "";
}

